# What is the symbol for enter in a ASCII table Python?

Tags: ascii, symbols

I would like to know what is the symbol for Enter in a ASCII table Python?

Answer (score 2):

The symbol for the Enter key cannot be found in the ASCII or Extended ASCII. The symbol normally has an arrow pointing down and left (⏎ (U+23CE) or ↵ (U+21B5) ), which is the symbol for carriage return. In contrast, the "Enter" key is commonly labelled with its name in plain text on generic PC keyboards, or with the symbol ⌤ (U+2324 up arrowhead between two horizontal bars) on many Apple Mac keyboards.

```
enter_key = "\u23CE" #or one of the Unicode values
```